# Nginx URL rewriting for 2 different CMS

Tags: php, nginx, joomla

I'm using Joomla/MariaDB and another CMS/PostgreSQL in the same server with Nginx as web server. The rewriting rules for joomla works as well, but doesn't work for the other one. The URL's structures from the PostgreSQL CMS looks like this:

```
http://example.com/dir/Something.php?somename=Blah_Setup/Otherstring.php
http://example.com/dir/Something.php?somename=Blah_Setup/Otherstring.php&new_blah=true
http://example.com/dir/Something.php?somename=Blah_Setup/Otherstring.php&include=General_Info&worker_id=new
```

This is what I have:

```
location /sis/ {
     rewrite ^(/sis)/Modules.php?modname=(.*/)\..*$ $1/$2  last;
}
```

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong, please?

Comment: Thank you for the spell correction Mr. Ford.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your rewrite rule:

- The `location /sis/` does not process URIs ending with `.php`, so they will never see your rewrite rule
- The query string (from the `?` onwards) is not considered as part of the rewrite pattern

You can easily extract the value of the `modname` parameter by using the predefined variable `$arg_modname`.

If all of the `/sys/Modules.php` URLs need to be rewritten, the solution is easily accomplished with an exact match location:

```
location = /sis/Modules.php {
    rewrite ^ /sis/$arg_modname last;
}
```

If only those URIs with an `$arg_modname` require a rewrite, you will need to wrap it inside an `if ($arg_modname) { ... }` block. But it does increase complexity so a simple example is more difficult to provide without seeing your entire server configuration.

Comment: I've tried this solution, but it gives me this answer:`Ajax get error
Status: error
HTTP status: Not Found
URL: http//example.com/dir/Modules.php?modname=Blah_Setup/Otherstring.php`